# No aparece el driver QMYSQL en PyQT6

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt6

Para acceder a bases de datos **MySQL** empleo el módulo **pymysql** de la forma:

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                       database='python',
                       user='root',
                       password=''
                       )
cursor = conn.cursor()
etc…
```

Todo funciona bien, pero cuando he tratado de hacer uso de **pyQT6** con **PySide6** me encuentro que no aparece el driver **QMYSQL**, como puede verse con el código siguiente:

```
from PySide6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        db = QSqlDatabase("QMYSQL")
        print("Available drivers", db.drivers())

        db.setHostName("localhost")
        db.setDatabaseName("python")
        db.setUserName("root")
        db.setPassword("")
        db.open()
        print (db.lastError().text())
etc...
```

El resultado me dice:

```
Available drivers ['QSQLITE', 'QMIMER', 'QODBC', 'QPSQL']
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

No recuerdo haberme dejado nada por instalar.

¿Tengo pendiente algún módulo?

¿Alguna solución para conseguir el driver **QMYSQL**?

Comment: No sabría ayudarte con el error, pero te doy mi opinión: a mi me ha dado un poco de problema usar la librería en su momento.  Además, qtsql no produce errores que puedan ser capturados por python, si no que `QSqlQuery.exec_` devuelve False si falla y el objeto de error se obtiene con `QSqlQuery.lastError()`. Adicionalmente, la unica ventaja que da qtsql con respecto a modulos como sqlalchemy es [`QSqlTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html) (un modelo que relaciona sql con QTableWidget). Yo no lo usaría.

Comment: Gracias @Dante. No me han hablado muy bien de pyQT + QSqlQuery. Trabajo con pymysql, así que haré uso de pyQT y el sistema clásico de acceso a MySQL.

Comment: Parece que por cuestiones de conflictos de licencias ese driver ya no viene en Qt, hay que compilarlo y añadirlo manualmente. Supongo que habrán binarios pre-compilados para determinadas plataformas. Ver [este hilo](https://forum.qt.io/topic/112775/qmysql-driver-setup) y [este otro](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#qmysql).